# Python convert CSV into Lists

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv

Im trying to read a CSV file (with one column) and convert them into Lists. The following is my code.

```
import csv

path = "/tmp/list.csv"
with open(path, 'r') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  your_list = list(reader)

print(your_list)
```

List.csv:

```
apple
banana
orange
pear
```

The code output:

```
[['apple'], ['banana'], ['orange'], ['pear']]
```

But do can I generate a output is the following format?

Expected output:

```
["apple","banana","orange","pear"]
```

Comment: try printing a few more things, for example reader, what else can you do with reader, https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/csv.html

Comment: import itertools
your_list = [['apple'], ['banana'], ['orange'], ['pear']]
result = list(itertools.chain(*your_list))

Comment: I managed to get this closer using "reduce(operator.concat, your_list)", also itertools work the same way. But the output is with single quotes, Can we modify in double quotes?